# How to save updated row?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, upgrade, save, data

Building my edu module but can't manage to create a "Save" button or use existing one. I can pick record from grid and open in edit form but now I would like to change some details and save it. Would anyone describe in few steps how should I do it please ?

Already checked many tutorials but nothing is obvious and still don't know how to ... :(

Comment: Please update the code what you have tried

Comment: Hello Martuza, I just hate posting whole code here so maybe if I could post link to the github ?